# Compare date to range of dates in CSV - BASH

Tags: bash, csv, while-loop, heredoc

I am trying to compare user input to a here doc to compare if the input is greater or lesser than 2 numbers (dates), and if it is I print the first column.
My file looks like this:

```
Earth,19480210,19490228
Earth,19490229,19500216
Metal,19500217,19510205
```

user could input 20100215 as the date. Here is my while loop which compares using  2 variables contained within a while read

```
while IFS=, read -r term start end; do
if [[ $query -ge $start && $query -le $end ]];then
    echo $term
fi
    echo $query
    exit
done << EOF
$(cat chzod)
EOF
```

The output looks like this: Your chinese zodiac is: Water

Fire

Earth

I do not know why the while loop generates multiple elements, and if there are any possible solutions to this. 
Thanks,
Kieran

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I am a bit lost, and I am not sure why it outputs multiple elements. I want to know if the while loop will work, or if I should find another solution.

Comment: Because of `echo $query`.

Comment: You are committing a ***UUOC*** (Unnecessary Use Of Cat). Any time you find yourself doing `cat ...` where you are not actually *concatenating* two (or more) files, it's probably a UUOC. Better, `while ...; do ... done <chzod` (presuming `chzod` is your data file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still a bit unclear, and I'm somewhat reading between the lines here, but if I'm guessing right, you want to loop over all entries in the CSV file, and if the `$query` falls between `start` and `end`, you want to output `term`. But, if after looping through the entire file, if no match is made, you are attempting to print out the query again?

If that is the case, then you are stumbling over the loop logic. There are many ways to handle this, but when executing multiple queries, of which you need to confirm whether a match was made, the easiest solution is simply to set a flag you toggle when a match is made. Then after completing all comparisons, you check the flag to see if it has been set.

A quick example would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-chzod}"    # take csv file as first argument (default: chzod)

printf "query: "       # prompt for query
read -r query

test -z query && exit  # validate query

declare -i matched=0   # declare matched flag, set to '0'

while IFS=, read -r term start end; do
    if [[ $query -ge $start && $query -le $end ]];then
        echo $term
        matched=1      # set 'matched' flag
    fi
done < "$fname"        # redirect CSV file into loop

# check 'matched' flag and if unset, output unmatched query
test "$matched" -eq '0' && echo "unmatched query: $query"
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your CSV file, you would expect the following example results:

```
$ bash readearth.sh dat/earth.dat
query: 19490229
Earth

$ bash readearth.sh dat/earth.dat
query: 19510204
Metal

$ bash readearth.sh dat/earth.dat
query: 20100215
unmatched query: 20100215
```

If I misinterpreted your intent, just drop me a line and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: I used your script to check for errors and it turns out my CSV file was full of them, I recreated it an the script works perfectly. Thank you for your help David, best wishes.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help. Good luck with your scripting.